# Does anyone knows the meaning of output of image_to_data, image_to_osd methods of pytesseract?

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm trying to extract the data from image using **pytesseract**. This module has **image_to_data**, **image_to_osd** methods. These two methods provides lot of info(TextLineOrder, WritingDirection, ScriptDetection, Orientation etc...) as output.

Below image is the output of **image_to_data** method. what does values of these columns(level, block_num, par_num, line_num, word_num) meaning?

[image]

Output of **image_to_osd** looks as below. What is the meaning each term in this?

Page number: 0
Orientation in degrees: 0
Rotate: 0
Orientation confidence: 16.47
Script: Latin
Script confidence: 4.00

I refered docs but I did not get any info regarding these parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Column **Level**:

1. Item with no block_num, paragraph_num, line_num, word_num
2. Item with block_num and with no paragraph_num, line_num, word_num
3. Item with block_num, paragraph_num and with no line_num, word_num
4. Item with block_num, paragraph_num, line_num, and with no word_num
5. Item with all those numbers

Column **block_num**: Block number of the detected text or item 
Column **par_num**: Paragraph number of the detected text or item 
Column **line_num**: Line number of the detected text or item 
Column **word_num**: word number of the detected text or item

But above all 4 columns are interconnected.If the item comes from new line then word number will start counting again from 0, it doesn't continue from previous line last word number. Same goes with line_num, par_num, block_num.

Check out the below image for reference.
1st column: block_num 
2nd column: par_num 
3rd column: line_num 
4rth column: word_num 
[image]

Answer (score 15):

[my_image.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH4Cc.png)

For example, Test the my_image.jpg with image_to_data in the following code, we will get the results like the results.png.

[results.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg5oV.png)

- level = 1/2/3/4/5，the level of current item.
- page_num: the page index of the current item. In most instances, a image only has one page.
- block_num: the block item of the current item. when tesseract OCR
  Image, it will split the image into several blocks according the PSM
  parameters and some rules. The words in a line often in a block.
- par_num: The paragraph index of the current item. It is the page
  analysis results. line_num: The line index of the current item. It is
  the page analysis results. word_num: The word index in one block.
- line_num: The line index of the current item. It is
  the page analysis results.
- word_num: The word index in one block.
- left/top/width/height：the top-left coordinate and the width and
  height of the current word.
- conf: the confidence of the current word,
  the range is -1~100.. The -1 means that there is no text here. The
  100 is the highest value.
- text: the word ocr results.

The meaning of the results from image_to_osd:

- Page number: the page index of the current item. In most instances, a image only has one page.
- Orientation in degrees: the clockwise rotation angle of the text in the current image relative to its reading angle, the value range is [0, 270, 180, 90].
- Rotate: Record the angle at which the text in the current image is to be converted into readable, relative to the clockwise rotation of the current image, the value range is [0, 270, 180, 90]. Complementary to the [Orientation in degrees] value.
- Orientation confidence:Indicates the confidence of the current [Orientation in degrees] and [Rotate] detection values. The greater the confidence, the more credible the test result, but no explanation of its value range has been found so far.
- Script: The encoding type of the text in the current picture.
- Script confidence: The confidence of the text encoding type in the current image.

from pytesseract import Output
import pytesseract
import cv2

```
image = cv2.imread("my_image.jpg")

#swap color channel ordering from BGR (OpenCV’s default) to RGB (compatible with Tesseract and pytesseract).
# By default OpenCV stores images in BGR format and since pytesseract assumes RGB format,
# we need to convert from BGR to RGB format/mode:
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
 
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\mypath\tesseract.exe'
custom_config = r'-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789 --psm 6'
results = pytesseract.image_to_data(rgb, output_type=Output.DICT,lang='eng',config=custom_config)
print(results)
```

Comment: This was very informative. However, you should have clarified what `level` means.